QGIS: can a symbol be the combination of symbol from the library?
It's, of course, possible to create a new symbol by aggregating several layers.
QGIS offer different types of "sub symbol" ; SVG, raster, basic symbol, font element, etc.
How is it possible to combine existing symbols from the QGIS libraries (Style manager) to create a new symbol?

Is it possible to combine two existing symbols (from the library) to create a new one, such as:

(ex : Triangle green + Topo pop capital symbol, as shown in the last screen of your answer)

Importing one full symbol into another doesn't appear to be possible. You can, however, export your desired symbols as SVGs and then stack them as symbol layers.
It's not the ideal solution as it requires some extra steps and you lose a lot of the flexibility of manipulating the indivual symbol layers.
Steps:
Export desired symbols as SVG to a location on your drive.

Add as many symbol layers to your target layer as you wish to combine. Set them as SVG Marker type.

Set the path for each layer to your exported SVG symbols and adjust sizes and offsets accordingly.


Note, bear in mind that the topo pop capital symbol is filled with white. If you want it to appear transparent as in your example, you will need to edit it and save it as a new symbol.

Thanks a lot for these accurate informations !
Best. Francis
